# Javascript Promises (Q) does not wait to be resolved before going to the next one

Tags: javascript, promise

I have this code which is trying to load a spreadsheet, and then it will need to do something, and then load it again:

```
var Q = require('q'),
    editGoogleSpreadsheet = require('edit-google-spreadsheet');


loadSpecificSheet = function(_spreadsheetName, _worksheetName) {
    return Q.ninvoke(editGoogleSpreadsheet, 'load', {
        debug: true,
        spreadsheetName: _spreadsheetName,
        worksheetName: _worksheetName,
        oauth: {
            email: superSecretEmail,
            keyFile: superSecretKeyfile
        }
    });
};


google.loadSpecificSheet(spreadsheetName, worksheetName).then(
    function(spreadsheet) {
        console.log("loaded")
    },
    function(err) { node.warn("sheet failed to load: " + err); }
).then(
    google.loadSpecificSheet(spreadsheetName, worksheetName).then(
        function(spreadsheet) {
            console.log("loaded 2")
        },
        function(err) { node.warn("sheet failed to load 2: " + err); }
    )
).catch(function(err) { node.warn("ToGoogleSheetNode Error: " + err); });

console.log("promises added to queue");
```

But, it is loading the spreadsheet 2 times simultaneously, as seen in the debug:

```
promise added to queue
Logging into Google...
Logging into Google...
Logged into Google
Searching for Spreadsheet 'Book1'...
Logged into Google
Searching for Spreadsheet 'Book1'...
Searching for Worksheet 'Sheet1'...
Searching for Worksheet 'Sheet1'...
loaded 2
loaded
```

Why is the second promise in the chain not waiting for the first promise in the chain?  I need it to wait...

Comment: You're passing the result of *calling*  `google.loadSpecficSheet()` into the second `.then()` call.

Comment: I thought that I might be invoking when I shouldn't be... how do I not invoke google.loadSpecficSheet(), but still give it the parameters it needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap that second `load` call in a function, and properly return values from your `.then()` callbacks:

```
google.loadSpecificSheet(spreadsheetName, worksheetName)
  .then(
    function(spreadsheet) {
      console.log("loaded");
      return spreadsheet;
    },
    function(err) { node.warn("sheet failed to load: " + err); }
  )
  .then(function() {
    return google.loadSpecificSheet(spreadsheetName, worksheetName)
  })
  .then(
    function(spreadsheet) {
      console.log("loaded 2");
    },
    function(err) { node.warn("sheet failed to load 2: " + err); }
  )
  .catch(function(err) {
      node.warn("ToGoogleSheetNode Error: " + err);
  });
```

(Note that I can't really test this.)

Comment: It did work.  I thought that since loadSpecificSheet was returning Q.ninvoke() that it was getting a promise there, but I guess Q.ninvoke() does not return a promise...

Comment: @mattnificent ok great! I should add "Google Spreadsheet APIs" to my resume :)